# How to calculate the rate of change of angle $\theta$ with respect to time, If the sine wave frequency is 30kHz?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, trigonometry

I am solving for the rate of change of magnetic field strength( ($\frac{dB}{dt}$) Because I want to calculate the induced emf after this) in a current carrying coil of 100 turns(Note: Current is changing), the coil is connected to a 30kHz sine wave function generator. And I got confused while taking derivative of angle $\theta$.

Formula for calculating Magnetic field strength $B$,

$$ B = (100)\frac{\mu \times I}{2\pi r} T $$
Where, $\mu$ is the permeability of the air. and $I$ is the current through the coil. and (100) is the number of turns of the coil. and $r$ is the radius(distance) from the coil.

Note: $\mu$ and $r$ are constants for our example but current $I$ is changing,

$$\frac{d(B)}{dt}= \frac{100\mu}{2\pi r} \times \frac{d(I)}{dt} $$

How fast is current changing with respect to time? The current is 30kHz sine wave in this case. (Let's just only for this example keep this fact aside that in an inductor current and voltage has 90 degree phase shift.) Hence,

$$\frac{d(I)}{dt}= \frac{d(sin(\theta))}{dt} $$
$$\frac{d(I)}{dt}= cos(\theta) \times \frac{d(\theta)}{dt} $$

Now, How fast is angle $\theta$ is changing with respect to time?
the frequency of the sin wave is 30kHz so,

$$ \frac{d(\theta)}{dt} = 30000 \times 2 \pi $$
Because in 1 second there will be 30k cycles completed of 2$\pi$ radians.

$$ \frac{d(\theta)}{dt} = 60000 \pi $$

Hence,

$$\frac{d(I)}{dt}= 60000 \pi \times cos(\theta) $$

So,

$$\frac{d(B)}{dt}= \frac{100\mu \times 30000 \times cos(\theta)}{r}  $$

Is the answer correct? I still don't really have an intuitive understanding of what is happing with the angle $\theta$. And what value I should put in $\theta$ to get the final answer, the rate of change of magnetic field strength $B$.

Comment: I am hoping for a "Yes correct" if the answer is correct.

Comment: And one more thing I didn't mentioned that the supply is 12v and and resistance is 48 ohm. So the peck to peck current will be 0.25 amps hence while mentioning current just as sin($\theta$) I should have mentioned 0.25sin($\theta$). But I didn't mentioned that because then this question will become a electronics problem not just the derivative part of it, which what I want.